If two IV yield distinct F-statistics in the first-stage regression, does it indicate that they are different IV, regardless of the correlation?
Suppose we are in a panel context where we are estimating while controlling for fixed effects. Let's assume that we have two instruments Z1 and Z2 for the X endogenous variable and both instrument are relevant. We regress Y on X by 2SLS using Z1 and using Z2, individually (two distinct regressions).
Scenario 1): Corr(Z1,Z2) > 0.8 but F-statistic from Z1 is 50 and F-statistic from Z2 is 90. Can we say that they are two different instruments?
Scenario 2): Corr(Z1,Z2) < 0.5 but F-statistic from Z1 is 85 and F-statistic from Z2 is 90. Can we say that they are two different instruments?
Now suppose that we try to evaluate the correlation between instruments by "removing" fixed effects. That is, just regress Z on fixed effects, save the residuals and then compute the correlation between residual from Z1 and residual from Z2. Lets call this "demeaned corr".
Scenario 1.1): demeaned corr(Z1,Z2) > 0.8 but F-statistic from Z1 is 50 and F-statistic from Z2 is 90. Can we say that they are two different instruments?
Scenario 2.1): demeaned corr(Z1,Z2) < 0.5 but F-statistic from Z1 is 85 and F-statistic from Z2 is 90. Can we say that they are two different instruments?
Any insights into whether the differences in F-statistics alone can be used to determine the distinctiveness of the instruments would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Why don’t you regress X on both Z1 and Z2 and try excluding them one at a time (t^2 = F)? Should tell you whether both are relevant.

Thank you, Jonathan! I understand your point. Our paper is already extensive, so we want to avoid delving into additional tests, such as the Hansen test or related F-statistics for multiple instruments explained by Andrews et al. (2019). Therefore, we aim to evaluate each instrument individually. Our reasoning is that if two distinct relevant instruments yield similar results, it would strengthen our overall conclusion. Is that make sense, right?

Checking if you get the same result with one instrument at a time (and the other as a control) should in principle be the same as doing a Sargan/Hansen test. I think it makes for a good informal test that is easy to understand (also report the coef/s.e. of the Z that is used as a control; it should be insignificant in the second stage regression). But I don’t see why you can’t do both, shouldn’t add more than a sentence to your paper. Up to you of course.
